# Mail Function - Fatal error: Function name must be a string

Tags: php

Need some help here - I have a table which presents a User with data: the User has the option to update the table. If the table is updated I want to generate an email with that (updated) data enclosed. Clear so far?

When I run the code it does update the database but sends the following error -

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in C:\xampp\htdocs\mlac\mlac_member2.php on line 226
```

OK - here is the relevent code (I have left out the rest because it adds nothing to this problem):

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['view']))
    {
    $user = sanitizeString($_GET['view']);




    $data = "SELECT * FROM names WHERE id='$user'";
    $result=mysql_query($data) or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

?>
```

html

```
    <caption>Personal Record</caption>

<tr>
<th>ID</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['id'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Name</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['name'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>E-Mail</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['email'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Main Telephone</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['maintel'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Mobile Telephone</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['mobtel'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Organisation</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['organisation'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Group Leader</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['group_leader'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Supervisor</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['supervisor'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Volunteer</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['volunteer'];
     ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<th>Assessor</th>
    <td><?php
        echo $row['assessor'];

        }
        }
     ?></td>
</tr>

</table>


    <br />
    <form method="post" action="update.php">
        <input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Edit" style="width: 67px" /></form>

    <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

[/html]

```
<?php   

$to='xy@sth.com';
$subject='Test Script';

$name=$row('name');
$email=$row('email');
$phone=$row('mobtel');
$message=("Name:  ").$name. ("\r\n") . ("Email:  ") .$email . ("\r\n") . ("Phone:  ")    .$phone;


mail($to,$subject,$message);

?>
```

If sanyone can help I would be grateful.

Regards,

Comment: try this $name=$row['name']; and also for other row elements

Comment: Please, next time, indicate which one is `line 226`.

Answer (score 1):

`$row` is not a function, it is an array (*I guess*).

```
$name=$row['name'];
$email=$row['email'];
$phone=$row['mobtel'];
```

Comment: Thanks Guys!! This seems to have fixed one problem.

Comment: But I now get, "Warning: mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\xampp"

Comment: I have a 'header page attached to this page in which I have defined various functions but I understood that the 'mail()' function was php generic and din't need to be defined every time.

Comment: @Hamish You need to define a `From:` header for your `mail` function. The PHP Manual on `mail()` has information about this. If you are unsure, please open a new question for this specific problem.

Comment: @Hamish Please click the tickmark to the left of my answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$name=$row['name'];
$email=$row['email'];
$phone=$row['mobtel'];
```

what bažmegakapa told is correct...And also remove the parantheses in the below line.

```
$message="Name:  ".$name. "\r\n" . "Email:  " .$email . "\r\n". "Phone:  ".$phone;
```

If you want to add headers to the mail, try like this

```
$headers1  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$headers1 .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

$headers1 .= "From: $fromurl\r\n";



@mail($to, $subject , $message, $headers1);
```

Comment: There is no problem with parentheses there. Even though they are unnecessary, they are syntactically correct.